# Getting Errors when pygame starts running

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, pygame

Error in console when ran:

```
--> python3 -m poetry init --no-interaction --name repl_python3_SycoBaksGame

This command will guide you through creating your pyproject.toml config.


You can specify a package in the following forms:
  - A single name (requests)
  - A name and a constraint (requests ^2.23.0)
  - A git url (git+https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry.git)
  - A git url with a revision (git+https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry.git#develop)
  - A file path (../my-package/my-package.whl)
  - A directory (../my-package/)
  - An url (https://example.com/packages/my-package-0.1.0.tar.gz)



pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default

```

---

**my code:**

```
import pygame

#Canvas Creation

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("SycoBaks Game")

#Position
x = 250
y = 250

#Size
width = 20
height = 20

#Velocity/Time
speed = 5


#SycoBak Main GameFrame

run = True

while not run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
      x=x-1
    
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
      x=x+1
    
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
      y=y-1

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
      y=y+1



    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

*Would love if something helped me resolve this error as i see nothing is wrong with my code, it could be a pygame dependency issue but im not aware**

Comment: There's a typo:  `while not run:`, but `run` is set to `True`, so your  main loop never runs.  You need `while run:`.

Comment: This bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=586150 (and other places) suggest that this could be a user-permissions error with Alsa.  Try temporarily running as root user.  There's also this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/37589/alsa-permissions

Comment: @Kingsley that might not be a typo... I think it is more like a flag allowing OP to run/not run the code when it isn't required... SycoBak please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

what does `pygame.init()` do is trying to initialize all the pygame modules for you [shown here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/ImportInit.html)

I think it is importing a module that requires some work(that you don't need) and forcing you to do some code that you don't need. try importing the module you need one by one.
You can `init()` every module that you need.